# Delete an entity without to delete the foreign key link to it

Tags: mysql, sql, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm

I have a table *Products* the entity *tva* is link to the table *Tva* and the entity *image* is link to the table *Media*. I render in sonata admin all the products of the website. I would like to be able to delete a product from the administration.

I want be able to delete a product without to delete the foreign key link to it.

But i have this error:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or
>   update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`fly`.`post`,
>   CONSTRAINT `FK_5A8A6C8D4D79775F` FOREIGN KEY (`tva_id`) REFERENCES
>   `tva` (`id`))

This is my entity tva and image

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="FLY\BookingsBundle\Entity\Tva", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true)
 */

private $tva;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="FLY\BookingsBundle\Entity\Media", cascade={"persist","remove"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true)
 */
private $image;
```

I decided to change the join column from this    `* @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true)`  to this `* @ORM\JoinColumn(onDelete="CASCADE")`  and it works i can delete the product but it also delete the foreign key and i don't want that because i have other product that use the same image and tva.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`(onDelete="CASCADE")` will delete the child record when parent record is deleted. If we don't want to delete the child record then we need to configure `onDelete="SET NULL"`. This will set the foreign key value to `null` in child record.

Comment: i tried with `onDelete="SET NULL"` , but it set all my foreign key to null. i have many products that use the same image. i don't want to delete  the foreign key or set it to null because all my others products also image going to be set null for them.  I just want to delete a product without to delete or set to null the foreign key . Because others products use the same foreign key.

Comment: Have a look at the documentation here : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html. You can only choose one of the provided reference options. i.e you can either try setting it to null or delete it.

Comment: Can you please update this example along with table structure in question?

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to fix my problem :) I removed this line : `cascade={"persist","remove"}`and i changed this line `* @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true)` to `* @ORM\joinColumn(onDelete="SET NULL")`

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="FLY\BookingsBundle\Entity\Tva")
 * @ORM\joinColumn(onDelete="SET NULL")
 */
private $tva;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="FLY\BookingsBundle\Entity\Media")
 * @ORM\joinColumn(onDelete="SET NULL")
 */
private $image;
```

Thank you so much @Darshan Mehta for your help. :)